# Riemann integrability of a function given a bounding inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded, decreasing function which satisfies $\Big|f\Big(\dfrac{k}{n}\Big)-f\Big(\dfrac{k+1}{n}\Big)\Big|\leq\dfrac{1}{n}$. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and conclude that $f(x)=1-x$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

So, in order for $f$ to be Riemann integrable we need the lower and upper integrals to be equal. We have the lower sum, $\displaystyle L(f,P)=\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-x_{n-1})\inf{f(x)}$ for some partition $P$, and this is equal to the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\inf{f(x)}$. However I am not quite sure how to apply the inequality we have to determine that the sup of this sum is equal to the inf of the upper sum.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1-x/2$ to see $f(x)=1-x$ can fail. Note also that "bounded" is redundant as $f(0)\ge f(x)\ge f(1)$ holds because $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partition $P_n = \{0,1/n,...,(n-1)/n,1 \}$. Let $m_k = inf \{ f(x) : x \in [(k-1)/n,k/n] \}$ and $M_k = sup\{ f(x) : x \in [(k-1)/n,k/n] \}$. As f is decreasing, it is easy to see that $\forall x \in [(k-1)/n,k/n], f((k-1)/n) \geq f(x) \geq f(k/n)$. As $f((k-1)/n)$ is an upper bound of $\{ f(x) : x \in [(k-1)/n,k/n] \}$  and is contained in the set, $M_k = f((k-1)/n)$. Analogously, $m_k = f(k/n)$.

Thus, we can write that:

$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}((f((k-1)/n)-f(k/n)) \cdot 1/n = 1/n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}((f((k-1)/n)-f(k/n))
 $$

Notice that $f((k-1)/n) - f(k/n) \geq 0$, thus $f((k-1)/n)-f(k/n) = |f((k-1)/n)-f(k/n)|$. Then we can conclude that:

$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) = 1/n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}((f((k-1)/n)-f(k/n)) < 1/n * n/n = 1/n$$

By the equivalent condition of integrability, for every $\epsilon >0$, choose $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $1/n < \epsilon$. Thus, there exists a partition $P_n$ such that $U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) < \epsilon$, hence f is integrable in $[0,1]$.